# App Attest - Hash verification of public key is failing

Tags: php, devicecheck

I'm implementing App Attest server verification on a PHP server.

I'm stuck on step 5 of the [Verify the assertion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/validating_apps_that_connect_to_your_server#3576643) documentation:

> Create the SHA256 hash of the public key in credCert, and verify that it matches the key identifier from your app.

At this point, I have the following variables:

```php
$credentialId = ... ; // Bytes extracted from the attestation authData
$credCert = openssl_x509_read($x5c[0]); // The certificate chain is verified elsewhere
$pKey = openssl_pkey_get_public($credCert); // Extract the public key
$keyPem = openssl_pkey_get_details($pKey)['key'];
```

I don't uderstand what should be SHA-256 encoded to result in `$credentialId` ($credentialId is correctly validated against the key identifier, as described in step 9).

What I tried so far:

- base64 decoding the `$keyPem` after removing the pem header and footers
- hashing the whole `$keyPem` altogether

Can someone point me in the right direction? What public key bytes should be extracted and hashed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.

#### TL;DR

```php
$pKey = openssl_pkey_get_details(openssl_pkey_get_public($credCert));
$pBytes = "\x04" . $pKey['ec']['x'] . $pKey['ec']['y'];

if (hash('sha256', $pBytes, true) === $credentialId) {
     // SUCCESS!!
}
```

[I published a Gist with my currently working solution](https://gist.github.com/gbalduzzi/0f2f14c3511da9e7811ad6f3a0175d06) for all the steps required by app attest in PHP.

#### Why this works

Apple expect the public key to be in the X9.62 uncompressed point format.

As per [this security exchange answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/185552), we can create the format by extracting the `x` and `y` points from the key, concatenate them and prepend them with a 0x04.

The `x` and `y` points are specified in the array returned by [openssl_pkey_get_details](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pkey-get-details.php) in the following format:

```php
[
    "bits" => 256,
    "key" => """
      -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n
      BLA BLA BLA BLA\n
      BLA BLA BLA BLA\n
      -----END PUBLIC KEY-----\n
      """,
    "ec" => [
      "curve_name" => "prime256v1",
      "curve_oid" => "1.2.840.10045.3.1.7",
      "x" => b"some random bytes",
      "y" => b"some random bytes",
    ],
    "type" => 3,
]
```